# How to schedule pipeline using APP Engine in Google cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, scheduler

I read google cloud scheduler to schedule my batch pipeline. 
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart

I want to run batch pipeline once in a day. I read that "APP ENGINE" can schedule pipeline. I tried to find out in stack-overflow and google, however I did not find how exactly app engine can schedule batch pipeline?
Is there any other way for scheduling batch pipeline using cloud scheduler?
One way i found out that keep pipeline running and every hour drop pub-sub message using cloud scheduler and run the job. But this is expensive and inconvenient operation.

I want to now how exactly app engine can help to schedule batch pipeline.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, you asked this question a few days ago at this link. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228055/how-to-run-gcp-batch-pipeline-using-google-cloud-scheduler

Its a pretty broad question.  I'd recommend you think about how to make it more specific -- what have you tried, what would be a good result, any code you have working already, etc.  See more at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), likewise you might wan to see about what to do when [no one answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to now how exactly app engine can help to schedule batch pipeline.

According to [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#is_there_a_built-in_scheduling_mechanism_to_execute_pipelines_at_given_time_or_interval):

You can automate pipeline execution by:

- Using Google App Engine (Flexible Environment only) or Cloud Functions.

More details on how to schedule batching pipelines using App Engine can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)

Let me know if this is helpful for you.

Comment: Still I am not clear about it. I have created app engine in the project. Added servlet in the app engine . Then created servelet                                                                                                                                                                   
@WebServlet(name = "dataflowscheduler", value = "/dataflow/schedule")
public class DataflowSchedulingServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    Batchpipleine.run();
  }
}

Comment: Do you mean `Batchpipeline.run()` instead of `Batchpipleine.run()?` Also use the cron.yaml from this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions). Please not all the details. Regarding your answer, the required fields in cron.yaml are `url` which is the URL in your app to which you want the Cron service to send job requests and should `url: /dataflow/schedule` and `schedule` which defines the schedule of the job. `target` is optional and it is the name of a specific service in your app.

Comment: To sum up the process:     1. create servlet to call your pipeline code,     2. Create a cron.yaml file to configure App Engine Cron Service,     3. Deploy cron job to app engine.

Comment: Do you mean Batchpipeline.run() instead of Batchpipleine.run()? What this means. I have one java class which Batchpipeline and I rename main method  run. This run method has windowing and other logic. (This was main class). am i doing right?

Comment: You have miss-typed Batchpipeline.

Answer (score 0):

```
Still I am not clear about it. I have created app engine in the project. Added servlet in the app engine . Then created servelet                        

@WebServlet(name = "dataflowscheduler", value = "/dataflow/schedule")
public class DataflowSchedulingServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    Batchpipleine.run();
  }
}    

Batchpipeline is the java class which has run method. Run method has all steps for pipeline execution like pubs reading message, windowing, storing to db etc.

Am I on right path ?

Cloud scheduler app :
Name : Test pipeline 
Description: This will trigger batch job
Frequency : */5**** 
Traget : /dataflow/schedule

Is target correct?

Is this way to run pipeline using app engine?
Do you have any guidance or process which include process to run pipeline using app engine other than  document mentioned above
```